# How to create a directory when using Blob storage with hierarchical namespace?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob Storage and enabled the hierarchical namespace option to get "real" directories. However I could't find documentation on how to create a directory using the API (NuGet package `Azure.Storage.Blobs`). Any hint on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I could't find documentation on how to create a directory using the API (NuGet package Azure.Storage.Blobs). Any hint on this?

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**`Code :`**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace x
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<name>;AccountKey=<key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string cn = "rithwik";
            string directoryPath = "dir1/dir2/";
            string b = directoryPath + "blob"; // creating a dummy blob

            BlobContainerClient cc = new BlobContainerClient(cs, cn);
            BlobClient bc = cc.GetBlobClient(b);

            bc.Upload(System.IO.Stream.Null);

            bool d = bc.Exists();
            Console.WriteLine("Directory creation status using the code Rithwik: " + d);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

`cn` is container name

`cs` is connection string

**`Output :`**

[image]

**dir1:**

[image]

**dir2 (Inside dir1) :**

[image]

This is how I create directories in Azure Data lake storage accounts.

Comment: ah ok, didn't know that this works "automatically". Thank you :-)